# Regular Expression for this term

Tags: php, regex

What would be the regular expression to extract 1944 from the following line :

```
vol. 9, no. 3, pp. 185-197, 1944
```

1944 is basically the year of Publication that i am trying to extract. I varies between 1900 and 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always the last part in the string, them you may use `$` do indicate that, and the year shall always be a 4 digit number, so for that you use `d{4}`.
Hence, the regex you want shall be :

`\d{4}$`

And if you ever want to test your regex, there is a pretty neat tool here : http://pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm , it also has the rules stated on the right side. :)

Comment: But does it ensure that it won't result the page number if you have something like following : `vol. 9, no. 3, pp. 1985-1997, 1944`

Comment: Add a `$` at the end and it will ensure it. So make it `[1-9][0-9]{3}$` . And if you ever want to test your regex, there is a pretty neat tool here : http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm , it also has the rules stated on the right side. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a better constraint, but maybe this:

```
,\s+(19\d\d|200\d|2010)
```

Do you know a specific citation style, for example? (MLA, APA, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the year will always be last:

```
\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Match any number between 1900 and 2010:

```
(19\d\d|200\d|2010)
```

If the date is always the last item on the line:

```
(19\d\d|200\d|2010)$
```

If there might be something after it, but it's always immediately after a page ref:

```
pp?\.\s*[-\d]+,\s*(19\d\d|200\d|2010)
```

Note: when designing a regular expression, it is usually very important to have a large selection of items to match that you can test on, so you can see what variation there might be in the possible inputs. One test item by itself is not commonly enough to design a bulletproof regex.

Answer (score -1):

try catch 4 digits together:

```
\d{4}
```

Comment: And if there's 1000 or more pages in the book?

Comment: @tim-cooper mate I think that user is asking just for a year into a string.

Comment: @tim-cooper OK, now I see want you mean something like: `vol. 9, no. 3, pp. 1850-1970, 1944`. Yes, you right...

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I got it working using this:

```
\b[1-9][0-9]{3}\b
```

This matches a number between 1000 and 1999 and i know the numbers before the 'year' are not going to be as large

Comment: But does it ensure that it won't result the page number if you have something like following : `vol. 9, no. 3, pp. 1985-1997, 1944`

Comment: page numbers can be more than 1000, right ?